# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract, only in particular test case

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

Here is my comparator function:

```
Arrays.sort(intervals, (a, b)->{
    return (a[0] > b[0]) ? 1 : ((a[0] < b[0]) ? -1 : ((a[1] > b[1]) ? 1 : -1)); 
});
```

I think I've clearly specified return value for each condition in a case when `a` and `b` are arrays of size `2`, but I don't know why I'm getting this error in a single test case while others run properly:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract:
    at line 903, java.base/java.utili.TimSort.mergeHi
    at line 520, java.base/java.utili.TimSort.mergeAt
    at line 448, java.base/java.utili.TimSort.mergeCollapse
    at line 245, java.base/java.utili.TimSort.sort
    at line 1442, java.base/java.utili.Arrays.sort
    at line 3, Solution.merge
    at line 54, __DriverSolution__.__helper__
    at line 84, __Driver__.main
```

Comment: 1) Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem. So the "MRE" will show how you create the two array with data and how you invoke the sort on the array. We should be able to copy/paste/compile/test the code to see the Exception. 2) Post the stack track in the question not as an image.

Comment: You never return 0 as a result (should be returned when a and b are equal).

Answer (score 1):

If you had failed to cover a case, your code wouldn't even compile.

As is, your code compiles, but it doesn't fulfill the requirements of a compare method. Different problem.

Here is the general contract:

1. If a<b and b<c, then a<c.
2. If a==b, then compare(a, b) **must** return 0.
3. If a<b then b > a.
4. you may throw exceptions if you want.

You've broken the contract: If I pass the same value to your compare method, the final case occurs, and -1 is returned, which is saying: 'a is below a', and that breaks the rule.

Expand that last node (the -1) to: `(a[1] < b[1]) ? -1 : 0`.

Comment: Are you sure about 3rd

Comment: Yeah, typo in 3. item.

Answer (score 0):

There is no symmetry when a[1] and b[1] are switched. The following would solve that.

```
return a[0] > b[0]) ? 1
       : a[0] < b[0] ? -1
       : a[1] > b[1] ? 1
       : a[1] < b[1] ? -1
       : 0;
```

The `Comparator` class should be used for such structural comparisons.
Something like:

```
Arrays.sort(intervals, Comparator.comparing(c -> c[0]).thenComparing(c -> c[1]));
```